# jquery selector must select an area without an element which is in the area

Tags: jquery-selectors

I use jquery click event for a div and the div area has an input element. Because the input element is in the div, when I click input, the click function works, but I don't want this action.
I looked at the selector page in Jquery's website, but I couldn't find this selector. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`nodeName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.nodeName) property of the [originating element](http://api.jquery.com/event.target) to see where the event originated:

```
$('#myDiv').click(function(event) {
    if (event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'input') {
        return; // ignore the event if it originated on an input element
    }

    // do the rest of your code
});
```

If you want a more complex query (e.g. using jQuery pseudoselectors), you can use [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is):

```
$('#myDiv').click(function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).is('input[name="foo"]')) {
        return; // ignore the event if it originated on an input element with the name foo
    }

    // do the rest of your code
});
```